# ggplot: how to add direct labels to each curve

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was trying to add direct label to each curve in my density plot. The label is something like plots in this [tutorial](http://directlabels.r-forge.r-project.org/motivation.html), however I can't get it worked.

Here is my data frame:

```
 values <- runif(1200, 35, 60)
 ind <- as.factor(rep(c(1:6), each=200))
 inout <- as.factor(rep(c(1:2), each =600))
 df <- data.frame(values,ind,inout)
```

Here is the density plot:

```
 ggplot(df) + 
    geom_density(aes(x=values, group=interaction(ind,inout), colour=factor(inout)), alpha=1) +
    geom_density(aes(x=values, group=inout, fill=factor(inout)), alpha=.4) +
    theme(text = element_text(size=25)) + 
    theme(legend.justification=c(1,1), legend.position=c(1,1)) + 
    guides(colour=FALSE) +
    scale_fill_discrete(name="Ave.",breaks=c("1", "2"),labels=c("S1", "S2"))
```

How can I add direct labels (i.e., 1 to 6) to each curve for two groups (i.e., S1 and S2)? Two averaged curves don't need to be labeled.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is answer in the tutorial (in your other post) your are mentioning that actually do what you are asking!